# Unable to Change Password Correctly

Tags: mysql, passwords

As much as I've tried I can't see why this code wouldn't work. Whenever I atmempt to change a password using this page, it says an incorrect password has been supplied.

This is the last page I have to get to work for this site, so any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
require_once ("dbconnect.php");

 // include file to do db connect

require_once ('checklog.php');

require_once ("functions.php");

session_start();
$username = ($_POST['username']);
$password = ($_POST['password']);
$newpassword = ($_POST['newpassword']);
$repeatpassword = ($_POST['repeatpassword']);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($username && $password) {
        $hashpass = salt($password);
        $query = "SELECT ID FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$hashpass'";

        if ($username == $datausername && salt($password) == $datapassword) {


            // PASSWORD CHANGING IS DONE HERE

            if ($newpassword == $repeatpassword) {

                // From register

                if (strlen($newpassword) > 25 || strlen($newpassword) < 6) {
                    $message = "Password must be 6-25 characters long";
                }
                else {

                    // part 8
                    // Process details here

                    if ($db_server) {
                        die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                        $db_status = "not connected";
                    }
                    else {
                        if ($db_server) {

                            // clean the input now that we have a db connection

                            $newpassword = clean_string($db_server, $newpassword);
                            $repeatpassword = clean_string($db_server, $repeatpassword);
                            mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database);
                            $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
                            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                $message = "This is your current password. Please try again.";
                            }
                            else {

                                // Process further here

                                $newpassword = salt($newpassword);
                                $query = "UPDATE INTO users (password) VALUES ('$password')";
                                mysqli_query($db_server, $query) or die("Insert failed. " . mysqli_error($db_server));
                                $message = "<h1>Your password has been changed!</h1>";
                            }

                            mysqli_free_result($result);
                        }
                        else {
                            $message = "Error: could not connect to the database.";
                        }

                        mysqli_close($db_server);

                        // include file to do db close

                    }
                }

                // This code appears if passwords dont match

            }
            else {
                $message = "<h1>Your new passwords do not match! Try again.</h1>";
            }
        }
        else {
            $message = "<h1>Incorrect password!</h1>";
        }
    }
    else {
        $message = "<h1>That user does not exist!</h1>" . "Please <a href='password.php'>try again</a>";
    }

    // Close connection!

}
else {
    $message = "<h1>Please enter a valid username/password</h1>";
}

?>



<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<?php
include_once ("header.php");
 ?> 
 <div id="apDiv1"><span class="rich-list">
<title>Change your Password</title>


<h1>So you want to change your password,  <?php
echo $_SESSION['username'];
?>?</h1>


<form action='password.php' method='POST'>

  <div align="right">Current Username:
  <input type='text' name='username'><br />
 Current Password: <input type='password' name='password'><br />
New Password: <input type='password' name='newpassword'><br />
Repeat New Password: <input type='password' name='repeatpassword'><br />

  <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Confirm'>

  <input name='reset' type='reset' value='Reset'>
  </div>
</form>

<?php
echo $message
?>

<?php
include_once ("footer.php");
 ?> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the many bad practices in your code for now, the problem is that you never retrieve the user's password from the database:

```
// $datausername and $datapassword have not been set, so this will always be false
if ($username == $datausername && salt($password) == $datapassword) {
    // ... code
} else {
    $message = "<h1>Incorrect password!</h1>";
}
```

You did set the $query string, but you forgot to run the actual query in the database and retrieve the results, if any.

To run a query, first you establish a database connection:

```
 $dbc = new mysqli("db_host", "db_user", "db_password", "db_name");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      die("Could not connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }
```

Let's assume you did that in your "dbconnect.php" file, so now you have a valid $dbc connection and your $query string. The following will give you a [mysqli_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object, or FALSE if the query fails.

```
$result = $dbc->query($query);
```

Please see the PHP manual for more information on how to use that object.

Also, PHP has an excellent built-in function called [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) - I suggest you use this instead of what appears to be a custom-defined function 'salt'.

To further improve your code, you should learn about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and how to avoid it, such as by using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Thank you for your help! So I need to run the query? How on earth do I make that run? I probably know this, but I've been at this since 9am and my mind has literally turned to mush.

Comment: I'm really sorry, apparently I just don't understand... I tried adding a MYSQL query and it's still just doing the same thing.

Comment: The query doesn't populate your $datapassword field automatically - you have to retrieve the row such as by using [fetch_assoc][1]. If that still doesn't make sense, I can add more code later, but there are examples within the documenation. [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the 'salt' function is defined - you might want to include it in your post.

I suspect that salt will pick some random salt, and hash with that - if so, to verify, you will need to use the salt from the encrypted password, or you will get a different outcome.

So, to verify a password:

- get the username and guess,
- get the encrypted password for the username
- get the salt from the encrypted password (often the first few characters)
- encrypt the guess with the salt from the encrypted password
- compare this encrypted guess to the encrypted password.